# Unable to retrieve json values to table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-table, react-bootstrap-table

```
const App = () => {

   const [symbol, setSymbol] = useState([]);
   const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
   const getSymbolData = async () => {
     try{
       const data = await axios.get("https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/market/batch?symbols=PGX,MORL,EMLC,GYLD");
       console.log(data);
       setSymbol(data.data);
     } catch (e) {
       console.log (e);
     }
   };

const columns = [

  {dataField: "price", text: "Current Price"},
  {dataField: "symbol", text: "Symbol" },
  {dataField: "companyName", text : "Company Name"}

];
 useEffect (() => { 
   getSymbolData();
   }, []);
  return (
   <div className="App"> 
  
      <BootstrapTable
      keyField= "symbol"
      data= {symbol}
      columns={columns}
      pagination={paginationFactory()}
      />  
  </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**JSON results** -

[image]

Console output:

> Blockquote

{data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config: {url: "https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/market/batc…s,quote&token=", method: "get", headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), …}
data: {PGX: {…}, MORL: {…}, EMLC: {…}, GYLD: {…}, IPFF: {…}, …}
headers:
content-type: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
**proto**: Object
request: XMLHttpRequest {readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, onreadystatechange: ƒ, …}
status: 200

Comment: If your code is an exact copy / paste, you are missing an ending double quote at the end of your URL.

Comment: You shouldn't upload images of code, read that: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: full code added.

Comment: @user:82609 Hi   can you please help me out with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error result, you are passing an object to data prop at
`<BootstrapTable data={symbol}>` which expects an array

Your axios response seem to be a big object, and this prop expects an array of objects

at first its defined as an array:

```
const [symbol, setSymbol] = useState([]);
```

but when you setState it becomes an Object (in view of the JSON response you showed) and that's when the error occurs

```
setSymbol(data.data);
```

see examples [here](http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/start.html) of how data is structured to work with BoostrapTable

Comment: thank you. can answer the questions using all of the code.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Failed to compile
./src/App.js
  Line 12:3:   'setSymbol' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 12:13:  'data' is not defined       no-undef
  Line 19:1:   'setSymbol' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 44:14:  'symbol' is not defined     no-undef

Comment: I am able to print the values from the browser console but not able to out put in the tables data:
ANGL:
quote: {symbol: "ANGL", companyName: "VanEck Vectors Fallen Angel High Yield Bond ETF", primaryExchange: "NASDAQ", calculationPrice: "close", open: 30.14, …}
stats: {week52change: 0.024889, week52high: 30.77, week52low: 21.13, marketcap: 3154797000, employees: null, …}
__proto__: Object
AOK: {stats: {…}, quote: {…}}

Comment: Make sure to check if the data you're putting into the table is an **array** of objects

Comment: I appreciate you time to help me on this. can you provide an example please

Comment: Of course. You see, your data starts with brackets { }, which are objects, what you need is an array of them, like [ { price: 13.99, symbol: "Symbol", companyName: "google" }, { price: 20.99, Symbol: "Symbol2", companyName: "facebook" } ], that way it can generate rows with data inside the bootstraptable component.

Comment: Something like this :   
  propTypes = {
    getSymbolData: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    symbol: PropTypes.object
  }

Comment: You could try in your axios response setSymbol([data.data])

Comment: sorry I am not making any progress still stuck.